# Is it possible to add request header to redirect URI?

Tags: java, jersey, response

I use Jersey create a sample API.

When client request this API, it will redirect client to anthoer URI.

The following is my code:

```
reidrectURI = URI.create(originalAlfDownloadLink);

return Response.seeOther(reidrectURI).build();
```

I want to add some customs http header into redirect uri.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, You can get hold of the httpRequest object and can add the desired headers before redirecting it. You can use the @Context annotation to get hold of the httpRequest.

```
@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest
```

Once you have the httpRequest object then you can add headers to it like this:

```
httpRequest.getSession().setAttribute("header", "value");
```

Comment: Hi Ahsan: So I cannot return Response object?

Comment: @bigd I think a filter can help you to do that